# Assert if the JMeter variable has incremented from the previous iteration

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter I'm doing a get request to check activeMQ queue size.

This request is made inside a Loop Controller that runs lets say 4 times.

In each iteration I'm extracting the value of `outQueueCount` into a JMeter variable.

How to do an assertion to verify that the current count value is greater than the previous iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns this `outQueueCount`
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def previousValue = vars.get('previousValue')

   if (previousValue == null) {
       vars.put('previousValue', vars.get('outQueueCount'))
   }
   else {
       long previous = previousValue as long
       long current = vars.get('outQueueCount') as long
       if (previous >= current) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Queue size not incremented: previous value: ' + previous + ', current value: ' + current)
       }
   }
   ```

If previous value will be greater than or equal to the new one - you will get an error message and the sampler will get failed:

[image: JMeter Groovy Assertion]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

if you have 2 JMeter variables with numbers you can check the difference between them with [__intSum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) function

```
 ${__intSum(${outQueueCount},-${currentCount},difference)}
```

`difference` will be a new JMeter variable with the result, then you can check if difference is 1 for example:

```
 ${__jexl3("${difference}" == "1")}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Add a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) as a child of your loop controller just before your request with the below configurations:

- **Start:** 1
- **Increment:** 1
- **Reference Name:** Counter

2) Add a [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of your request after your regular expression extractor with the below script in the script area:

```
String Counter = vars.get("Counter");
vars.put("MyVar_" + Counter, vars.get("MyVar"));// MyVar is the name of your regular expression extractor.
```

3) Add a [BeanShell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) after the above BeanShell PostProcessor with the below script in the script area:

```
int Counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Counter"));
if(Counter > 1){
int Prev = Counter - 1;
int CurrentCount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("MyVar_" + Counter));
int PrevCount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("MyVar_" + Prev));
if(CurrentCount < PrevCount){
Failure = true;
FailureMessage = "CurrentCount = " + CurrentCount + " is less than " + "PrevCount = " + PrevCount;}}
```